# Update or create Element with useState

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of elements and I want to update one property. I only know the id (not the position)
I want to set active: false for the element with id 2

```
const [data, setData] = [{id: 1, active: true}, {id: 2, active: true}]
const updatedData = {id: 2, active: false}
setData((prevState) => [...prevState, ??]);
```

where should I check if element with id=2 update it otherwise add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would map over data and if `id` matches, update the entry. If no mutation / update occured at the end of iteration push `updatedData` to the end of the array. Finally return the new state

```js
setData((prevState) => {
    let contains = false;
    const newState = prevState.slice(0);
    for (let i = 0; i < newState.length; i++) {
        if (newState[i].id === updatedData.id) {
            newState[i] = updatedData;
            contains = true;
        }
    }
    if (!contains) {
        newState.push(updatedData);
    }
    return newState;
});
```

Comment: 'hey  thanks for your help. this is only updating but not creating if it doesnt exist right?

Comment: @handsome Map is a 1-1 relationship. For every element in the original array, an element is returned in the new array.

Comment: And how to add the element if is not found? That’s the part that’s confusing me

Comment: @handsome Sorry did not see that part of your question. Have updated answer